# T(n)=T(n-1)+O(log n)$is T(n)=O(n^2) or T(n)=O(n log n)

Tags: recursion, big-o

I have this Recurrence relation: T(n)=T(n-1)+O(log n)

What is the solution?  T(n)=O(n^2) or T(n)=O(n log n)

What I did is:  I assume that   T(n)<=O(n^2)...
[image]

And that's bring me to O(n^2), I'm right?
Or I have mistake? 
(I heard from someone that he got O(n log n) and I'm curies if I'm right or him...)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if T(n)<=T(n-1) + c log n for some c
>
> => T(n) <= T(n-2) + c log (n-1) + c log n
>
> => T(n) <= T(n-3) + c log(n-2) + c log(n-1) + c log n
>
> thus: T(n) <= T(0) + sum_{i=1 .. n} c log i = O(n log n)
>
> but O(n^2) is also right but less specific, since  T(n) = O(n^2) means
>
> there are some a, m such that T(n)<=a n^2 for all n>=m